# Вызов метода класса C# в конкретное время по графику с помощью агента sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Есть несколько классов C#, нужно в разное время вызывать методы каких-то из этих классов, как это можно реализовать с помощью агента sql server?

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько способов сделать такой вызов с помощью SQL Server Agent:

1. Создать консольное .Net приложение для вызова вашего кода, в агенте выбрать `Operating system (CmdExec)`
   **Важно:** консольное приложение должно в случае успеха возвращать `0` или любой отрицательный `int` код в случае ошибки.
2. Создать SSIS пакет с блоком `Script task` для вызова вашего кода, в агенте выбрать `SQL Server Integration Services package`
3. Вызвать ваш код из скрипта Powershell, в агенте выбрать `PowerShell`.
   **Важно:** т.к. политика безопасности Windows по умолчанию не позволяет выполнять не подписанные скрипты - необходимо подписать скрипт сертификатом или перевести уровень безопасности для запуска не подписанных скриптов командой `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Comment: Как с помощью PowerShell обратиться к конкретному классу в коде?

Comment: все зависит от того, каким образом код оформлен: сборка/библиотека или просто cs файл

Comment: @kosmo_tony сначала нужно загрузить сборку. Потом можно сделать так: `[ИмяКласса]::ИмяСтатическогоМетода()`

Comment: @Serge Nazarenko если просто файл cs, то как? Нужно обратиться к конкретному классу и выполнить его метод.

Comment: @kosmo_tony в данном примере показано как это сделать https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881346/8484676

Comment: @SergeNazarenko можете порекомендовать хороший (времени занимает немного, но информации хватит для начала) tutorial по PowerShell?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko с C++ тоже можно так сделать (вызвать конкретный класс скриптом)?

Comment: Не знаю не пробовал с С++

Comment: @PavelMayorov сборку надо загрузить в самом скрипте powershell?

Comment: @kosmo_tony да, через Add-Type